# Change an excel formula cell into a vba macro

Tags: vba, excel

Please I need to change this formula:

```
=IF(VAL.EMPTY(K15);"";MAX(K15-Today();0))
```

This formula gives the difference between two dates:

1) i.e. K15: 30/10/2017

2) Today()

The maximum countdown stops at 0.

I need to transform this formula in a macro in order to insert this bit of code in a macro ran by `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`.

Comment: FWIW - Your formula is missing a `)` to finish the `IF` function.

Comment: Do you need the whole code or just a hint how to to this?

Comment: I will try first with an hint first and I see if it fits in my code. What I have tried until now without success was this piece of code:

Comment: I will try first with an hint and I see if it fits in my code. What I have tried until now without success was this piece of code:                                                                                                            sheet2.Range (M15:M38).Formula = "(=IF(ISBLANK(K15),"",MAX(K15-TODAY(),0))"

Comment: As a hint - look at `DATEDIFF` or just `Sheet1.Range("K15") - Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope the below code line should work, tested working fine for me.

```
 Sheet2.Range("M15:M38").Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK(K15),0,MAX(K15)-TODAY())"
```

too many arguments for IF function in your code. also you may use 0 instead of "" to keep a simple string of formula.